# does function find in strings in c++ work only with the first char?

Tags: c++

I want to find a `char` in a `string` consists of numbers and chars , if it's found the program does some operations , but when I use function `find()` , it returns only true if the char I am looking for is ONLY at the **beginning** of the string !!!!!

Ex :  This is part of the problem !
The user enters 3 strings s1 , s2 , s3 ; between the first 2 strings there's char `'a' = '+'` and between s2 and s3 there's char `'b' = '='`  (The 3 strings are supposed to be numbers ) but if s2 is a word that includes the letter `'m'` , the program converts s1 and s3 into integeres and writes the full operation 
ex : if i/p is    3247 + 5machula2 = 3749
then o/p would be 3247 + 502 = 3749

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABSYS/
and this part of  my code which has the problem  :

```
int T;
int x,y,z;
string s1 ;
string s2  , s3 ;
char a , b;
cin>>T;
for(int i=0 ; i<T ; i++)
{
         cin>>s1>>a>>s2>>b>>s3;


for (int k=0; k<s2.size(); k++)
{ 
    if (k==s2.find("m"))
    {     
        stringstream ss(s1);
        stringstream ss3(s3);

        ss>>x;
        ss3>>z;

        cout<<s1<<" "<<a<<" "<<z-x<<" "<<b<<" "<<s3<<endl;
    }   
    else break;       
}
```

This is a loop that loops on the second string and if it find a char `'m'` it should do what's mentioned above , but the problem here is that it only works if `'m'` is at the beginning of the string and no place else.

Comment: Please write and post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which recreates the problem you are asking about.

Comment: `find` returns the position of the found character and you break when it's not found at position 0.

Comment: here's the problem i'm trying to solve http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABSYS/

Answer (score 1):

Your `else break;` prevents the loop from ever looping.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it only works when it's at the beginning is because you break out of the loop if it isn't, so it has no chance to check the rest:

```
[first iteration]
if (0 == s2.find("m")) //if found at beginning
    //do stuff
else break; //exit loop if not found at beginning
```

Instead of the loop, if you're just trying to see whether there is an m, just use `find()`:

```
if (s2.find('m') != std::string::npos)
    //"m" found in string, do the operations on s1 and s3
```